# Django Rest Framework - return different serializer in same viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:
where

```
class Hunter(Model):
    name = CharField()
```

searches for

```
class Target(Model):
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKey(User) 
    approved_hunters = ManyToManyField(Hunter)
```

my serializers are

```
class AnonymousTargetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        name = 'target'
        model = Target
        fields = ['id',]
```

and also

```
class TargetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        name = 'target'
        model = Target
        fields = ['id',]
```

Im my viewsets I would like to:

```
hunter = Hunter.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
if hunter in Target.approved_hunters.all()
    return TagetSerializer
else:
    return AnonymousTargetSerializer
```

However I only seem to get this done for the viewset, but cannot filter on an individual object level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to modify representation of object based on some attribute you can override serializer's [`to_representation`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj) method:

```
class TargetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        name = 'target'
        model = Target
        fields = ['id',]

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        hunter = Hunter.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
        if hunter not in Target.approved_hunters.all():
            return AnonymousTargetSerializer(obj).data
        return super().to_representation(obj)
```

In viewset you dont need any customization, just use `TargetSerializer`:

```
serializer_class = TargetSerializer
```